# Wordpress random redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have this situation where I have categories and pages and some other items that have the same name like this:

```
example.com/category/house - category
example.com/house - page
```

Permalinks are set with Name only like this

```
example.com/%postname%/
```

Category prefix is *category* and tag prefix is *tag*

The problem is that WP will randomly redirect or not users from category page. If I access example.com/category/house it will go to category page 2-3 times and then it will do a 301 redirect to example.com/house. The behavior is absolutely random and it is completely unpredictable with respect to the moment when the redirect will occur.

I installed the query monitor plugin to see what might cause that and I found that multiple rules are matched for the same url natively in WP and I do not know how to fix this.

This is the output of the rules:

```
All Matching Rewrite Rules
Rule                        Query
category/(.+?)/?$            category_name=$matches[1]
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$     pagename=$matches[1]
                            &page=$matches[2]
[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$             attachment=$matches[1]
```

Wordpress version is 4.9

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome in both normal and incognito. The issue has been reported by other users as well.